# get full highscore list out of GameCenter

Tags: ios, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I'm trying to get a full highscore list out of GameCenter.
Unfortunately only current users highscore is listed although rank is published from 1 to 10 by using `leaderBoardRequest.localScore.value` and `leaderBoardRequest.localScore.rank`

How do I get full highscore list from some `leaderBoardRequest.identifier` let's say all names and values from current highscore for a particular game counting rank 1 to 10?

Any idea how to handle this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Regards.
simoasis

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick.
It will return an array of GKScore, which, in itself, has a GKPlayer property. 
(you can find more about GKScore here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/index.html )

```
        let leaderboard = GKLeaderboard()
        leaderboard.identifier =  kLeaderboardIdentifier
        leaderboard.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler({ (objects, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                for score in objects {
                    if let score = score as? GKScore {
                        // handle your score here
                    }

                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I'm getting:
`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
in `if let score = score as? GKScore`

Comment: fixed
when declaring GKScore outside if-clause everything works fine :)